# scratchbox2 error -- make install

Tags: cross-compiling, qemu, scratchbox

I am getting following error with scratchbox, make install

```
$ cd $HOME/sbox2/src
$ git clone git://gitorious.org/scratchbox2/scratchbox2.git
$ cd scratchbox2
$ git checkout 2.3.90 -b devel_env
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/sbox2/bin/scratchbox
$ make install
```

Error i got after make install :---

```
ignite@ignite:~/sbox2/src/scratchbox2$ make install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ignite/sbox2/src/scratchbox2'
echo "/* Automatically generated file. Do not edit. */" >include/scratchbox2_version.h
echo '#define SCRATCHBOX2_VERSION "'`cat .version`'"' >>include/scratchbox2_version.h
echo '#define LIBSB2_SONAME "'"libsb2.so.1"'"' >>include/scratchbox2_version.h
[CC] sblib/sb_log.o
[ARCHIVE] sblib/libsblib.a
[SHLIB] preload/libsb2.so
[CC] utils/sb2dctl.o
In file included from /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:251:0,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/in.h:25,
                 from utils/sb2dctl.c:25:
utils/sb2dctl.c: In function ‘recvfrom_nomap_nolog’:
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/socket2.h:65:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘recvfrom’: mismatched arguments
utils/sb2dctl.c:166:2: error: called from here
make[1]: *** [utils/sb2dctl.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ignite/sbox2/src/scratchbox2'
make: *** [regular] Error 2
```

Please suggest how can i solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off gcc optimization on sb2dctl by editing line 28 of utils/Makefile adding -O0 (that's minus capital-oh zero) after CFLAGS) as shown below.

```
# sb2dctl, a tool for communicating with sb2d
$(D)/sb2dctl: override CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -O0 -Wall -W -Werror \
```

Had similar error on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit using gcc 4.7.2 and above worked for me. Possibly caused by a gcc inlining bug.